# in release mode CompilationClass.GetAssembliesFile method fetchs different set of files

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, dynamic-compilation

My windows app does run-time compilation of code written by user.
In debug mode, **CompilationClass** instance fetch few files which is needed by app.
But in release mode same class instance fetch files from different location and hence error occurs.

// just sample piece of code

```
    CompilationClass cc = new CompilationClass();
        List<string> TotalAssemblyFiles;

    public Form1()
    {
        TotalAssemblyFiles = cc.GetAssembliesFile();      // Error in this line      
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Not sure what to do.. and issue occurs only in release mode. I'm not even specifying any path still.

```
    // Code for GetAssembliesFiles method

 public List<string> GetAssembliesFile()
        {
            List<string> myAssemblies = new List<string>();

            if (!File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\assemblies.sft"))
            {
               // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                BinaryFormatter binary = new BinaryFormatter();
                Stream sreader = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\assemblies.sft", FileMode.Open);

                myAssemblies = (List<string>)binary.Deserialize(sreader); // Issue
                sreader.Close();
            }
            return refAssemblies;

        }
```

In debug mode, myAssemblies fetchs 221 files while in release mode it fetch 355 files

Comment: The location of output in release mode is different, it stores in "bin\Release". Where do you store your assemblies?

Comment: location is "bin\release" only.. but cc.GetAssembliesFile() fetch files from different location which is different from location in debug mode.

Comment: How do you fetch your assemblies, would you please add cc.GetAssembliesFile() implementation?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh - please see code for GetAssembliesFile() implementation

Comment: Check the value of Environment.CurrentDirectory in both of modes. Are they are same?

Comment: Do you have different assemblies.sft file that stores different file paths?